# Class type return

Tags: java

I have been reading about JAVA and I am confused about the Class class. Suppose say you have this code here:

```
class C {}

public class NewClass {

  public Class<?> f(Class<?> type){
   return type.getClass();
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();  
    C c = new C();
    System.out.println(nc.f(C.class));    
 }
}
```

Now it is really surprising for me that the getclass returns java.lang.Class whereas I was expecting it to be packagename.C. How is it not showing the actual class where as the Class class?

Also, when I try to pass new C() in f() it doesnt compile. Even c (reference of C) isnt accepted. Why is this the case? Even they are the same class object/reference? why only C.class, that is, class literals are accepted as Class types?? This is really confusing me. If someone could please help?

thanks in advance

Comment: read more about java and OOP

Answer (score 2):

The Class of a Class object has to be `Class`, otherwise it wouldn't be `Class` object.

What you are doing is NOT "What is the class of C", but "What is the Class of the Object I get when I call `c.getClass()`" (or `C.class`), which is, Class.

```
C c = new C(); // c is on Object of type "C" here
Class<?> clz = c.getClass(); // clz is an Object of type "Class C" here.
Class<?> clzClz = clz.getClass(); // clzClzs is always "Class"
```

This calls `getClass()` on an Object that is already a `Class` object and so your get "java.lang.Class":

```
 public Class<?> f(Class<?> type){  // type IS already a "Class" object
   return type.getClass();   // so this will always be "java.lang.Class"
  }
```

You could replace that with...

```
 public Class<?> f(Object o){
   return o.getClass();
  }
```

...which then would return "C" Class later. but of course, this method would be useless, as it only class `getClass()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So basically I'm getting the class of C and not the class of the instance of C. That's interesting because C.class is actually the class object I thought. However, can you please tell me that if only class literals can be passed as a parameter foot type class? Like I mentioned, it doesn't accept new C(); or c as a parameter? Only class literals are accepted for Class type arguments? Thanks again. Sorry it my question sounds kind of dumb. It's kind of confusing you know.

Comment: Simplified, the "class" of an object is just another property of this object, a property that all objects have. And this property is always a `Class` object, which stores information about the name of the class, etc. For example, every String has a Class object with the name "java.lang.String" as name. And now, of course, every class object itself ALSO has class property, where the name is "java.lang.Class". If you give "Class<?> ..." as an argument in a method, you can only put Class objects there. And to get the Class object of any object, you call `getClass()`.

Comment: So I just tried passing c.getclass() as the parameter and it works similarly. So you're right that we need to pass Class objects. So now I understand that why passing c wouldn't work because it's just an object reference and not really an object per se.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're passing a Class instance to f(). You could see the actual class like this:

```
class C {}

public class NewClass {

  public Class<?> f(Class<?> type){
   return type.getClass();
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();  
    C c = new C();
    System.out.println(c.getClass());    
 }
}
```